# Method 'Union' of Object '_Global' failed

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I keep obtaining this error on my second export of a excel spreadsheet.

The recurring answer I have seen is that the rng used in the union needs to be set to nothing. I have done that over and over across my code to no avail, is there something else I might be missing.

Would appreciate any insight on this.

```
Set myRange = ApXL.Sheets(xlWSh.Name).Range("1:1")
Set LastCell = myRange.Cells(myRange.Cells.count)
Set FoundCell = myRange.Find(what:=fnd, After:=LastCell)

If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
  FirstFound = FoundCell.Address
Else
  GoTo NoValuesMatchingFound
End If
Set rng = FoundCell

'Loop until cycled through all unique finds
Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
  'Find next cell with fnd value
  Set FoundCell = myRange.FindNext(After:=FoundCell)
  'Add found cell to rng range variable
  Set rng = Union(rng, FoundCell)
  'Select Cells Containing Find Value
  'Test to see if cycled through to first found cell
  If FoundCell.Address = FirstFound Then Exit Do
Loop

 rng.EntireColumn.Select
 ApXL.Selection.NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yy  hh:mm:ss"

'Error Handler
NoValuesMatchingFound:
' Debug.Print "No values were found in this worksheet"

' selects all of the cells
 ApXL.ActiveSheet.Cells.Select
 ' does the "autofit" for all columns
 ApXL.ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
 ' selects the first cell to unselect all cells
 xlWSh.Range("A1").Select

 On Error Resume Next
 xlWBk.Sheets("Sheet2").Delete
 xlWBk.Sheets("Sheet3").Delete
 On Error GoTo 0

 With xlWBk
   If cmbOverwrite <> "Prompt" Then
     ApXL.DisplayAlerts = False 
   Else
     ApXL.DisplayAlerts = True
   End If
   .SaveAs FileName:=txtSaveToFolder & "\" & File_Name & ".xlsx"
   Set rng = Nothing
   .Close
 End With
 rstXX.Close
```

Comment: *The recurring answer I have seen is that the rng used in the union needs to be set to nothing.* - where did you read that? `Set foo = Union(Range("A1"), Nothing)` raises run-time error 5 'invalid procedure call or argument'. IOW you need to check for `foundCell Is Nothing`, and make sure you don't give `Union` any reference that's not set.

Comment: FWIW (not related to the error) - it would make be more logical if your `If FoundCell.Address = FirstFound Then Exit Do` was done before `Set rng = Union(rng, FoundCell)` or else you add the first found cell twice (not that it would matter - it would just ignore the second add)

Comment: Apologies for not expanding when originally posting as I was very tight on time, however what I was trying to get across was that the same error posted on this forum suggests (especially if thrown on second export/run) that the workbook rng had not been previously cleared. All I wanted to get across was that I had already tried that solution.  E.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840956/vba-method-union-of-object-global-failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
Set rng = Union(rng, FoundCell)
```

to be

```
Set rng = ApXL.Union(rng, FoundCell)
```

because you are trying to use the `Union` command which is part of the Excel Application object.

Comment: Went completely over my head that one, there were other objects in my code which I also had to use the ApXL object. Thanks for the tip. For anyone searching for a similar problem, changed to Set rng = ApXL.Union(rng, FoundCell)

Comment: @CodeStack Oops - I just noticed that I switched your object name when I typed the answer - I used `xlAp` when you were using `ApXL`  (answer now edited - hopefully you noticed anyway)

Comment: this is cumbersome... was desperately looking for this hint. In the Microsoft examples they usually never specify the complete objects (which would help dramatically to understand the relations). Thanks @YowE3K