# Looping through Ranges - Union

Tags: vba, foreach, range, union

I am getting an error while trying to loop through my ranges.. "Method 'Union' of '_Global' failure". Please someone help...After the update code I got, "Unable to get the Union property of the Application class"

```
    Dim chuteRG As Range, stowRG As Range, pickRG As Range, shipdockRG As Range, allRG As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set chuteRG = shChuteBowler.Range("F4:S18")
    Set stowRG = shStowBowler.Range("F4:S14")
    Set pickRG = shPickBowler.Range("F4:S12")
    Set shipdockRG = shShipDockBowler.Range("F4:S17")
    Set allRG = Union(chuteRG, stowRG, pickRG, shipdockRG).Cells

    For Each cell In allRG
        If cell = "0" Then
            cell = "X"
        End If
    Next cell


UPDATED - Still not working

    Dim chuteRG As Range, stowRG As Range, pickRG As Range, shipdockRG As Range, allRG As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim ApXL As Object

    Set ApXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set chuteRG = shChuteBowler.Range("F4:S18")
    Set stowRG = shStowBowler.Range("F4:S14")
    Set pickRG = shPickBowler.Range("F4:S12")
    Set shipdockRG = shShipDockBowler.Range("F4:S17")

    Set allRG = ApXL.Union(chuteRG, stowRG, pickRG, shipdockRG).Cells

    For Each cell In allRG
        If cell = "0" Then
            cell = "X"
        End If
    Next cell
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Method 'Union' of Object '\_Global' failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44164753/method-union-of-object-global-failed)

Comment: try changing it to `Set allRG = Union(chuteRG, stowRG, pickRG, shipdockRG)`, so omit the `.Cells` part, because that works on my sheet.

Comment: Still not working :/ .. By chance a specific reference I would need for this?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. You need to add `ApXL.` before calling `Union`.

```
Dim chuteRG As Range, stowRG As Range, pickRG As Range, shipdockRG As Range, allRG As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set chuteRG = shChuteBowler.Range("F4:S18")
Set stowRG = shStowBowler.Range("F4:S14")
Set pickRG = shPickBowler.Range("F4:S12")
Set shipdockRG = shShipDockBowler.Range("F4:S17")

Set allRG = ApXL.Union(chuteRG, stowRG, pickRG, shipdockRG).Cells 'AMENDED

For Each cell In allRG
    If cell = "0" Then
        cell = "X"
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: Ok try changing it to `Set allRG = Union(chuteRG, stowRG, pickRG, shipdockRG)`, so omit the `.Cells` part, because that works on my sheet.